# Remove duplicate algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

So i have created a array with a few duplicate and i have created a algorithm which will spot the duplicates and change the value to 0. After i change the value to 0, it will find all the values at 0 and override them.

```
   for(out = 0;out < array.length - 1;out++)
       for(in = out+1; in < index;in ++)
           if(array[in] == array[out])
               array[in] = 0;
   for(int n = 0;n < array.length;n++)
       if(array[n] == 0){
           array[n] = array[n + 1];
           n--;
```

However it does not seem to be running and when i do make a few tweaks to get it to run, it does not override the elements and decrease the size of the array, anything i'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest looking up the term `recursive` function. Recursion should be generally avoided like plague, but in your case it may help.

Comment: What's your purpose for doing this?

Comment: Yes. You dont have curly braces.

Comment: this is not Python, sorry. Braces are mandatory for blocks that have more than 1 statement

Comment: There is only one brace missing: the closing brace after `n--;`. Everything else is 1 statement.

Comment: When you say "override the elements and decrease the size of the array", do you mean you just want to delete all of the elements and return the rest?

Answer (score 2):

You need curly braces (`{` and `}`). Without them, you're only executing the next line but nothing else afterwards.

For example:

```
if(x == y)
    y = 1;
    System.out.println("Not inside if");
```

Only `y = 1` will execute in result of `x == y` returning `true`. The `System.out.println("Not inside if")` will always be executed because it's outside of the `if` conditional statement.

If you want to have both lines run ONLY when `x == y`, you can do the following:

```
if(x == y) {
    y = 1;
    System.out.println("Not inside if");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a curly brace problem. The lack of braces is fine (except for the missing closing brace at the end). Not very readable, but legal java.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm should be two pass. First you mark all duplicates with zero

```
for(out = 0;out < array.length - 1;out++)
    for(in = out+1; in < index;in ++)
       if(array[in] == array[out])
           array[in] = 0;
```

Then you compute what need to be put at the marked positions and override them.

```
              for(int i = 0;i < array.length;i++)
                    if(array[i] == 0)
                         array[i] = newvalue(i);// array[i + 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to remove elements from an existing array. You can't do that. Instead, you have to create a new array and populate it with only the elements that you want to keep.

One slick way to do that is by using an `ArrayList`. This will allow you to remove the duplicates in a single pass.

```
ArrayList<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
for (int out = 0; out < array.length; out++) {
    for (int in = out + 1; in < array.length; in++) {
        if (array[in] == array[out]) {
            myList.remove(in);
            in--;
        }
    }
}
```

Or, more in the pure-array spirit of your original:

```
int newLength = array.length;
for(int out = 0; out < array.length; out++) {
    for(int in = out + 1; in < array.length; in++) {
        if (array[in] == array[out]) {
            array[in] = 0;
            newLength--;
        }
    }
}

int[] newArray = new int[newLength];
int i = 0;
for(int n = 0; n < array.length; n++) {
    if (array[n] != 0) {
        newArray[i] = array[n];
        i++;
    }
}
```